# PHP / PDO : Delete image on server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The purpose of the following script is to delete an entry in my annonces table using provided "id".

I would like also delete a file with name $imageAnnonce which is stored in the following folder : /uploads

How can i do that using PHP ?

```
<?php

$PARAM_hote='aaaaaaaa'; 
$PARAM_port='3306';
$PARAM_nom_bd='bbbbbbbbbbb'; 
$PARAM_utilisateur='cccccccccccc'; 
$PARAM_mot_passe='ddddddddddddd';
// Create connexion to BDD
$connexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$PARAM_hote.';port='.$PARAM_port.';dbname='.$PARAM_nom_bd, $PARAM_utilisateur, $PARAM_mot_passe);

try {

    // GET POST DATA
    $idAnnonce = $_POST['idAnnonce'];
    $imageAnnonce = $_POST['imageAnnonce'];

    // PREPARE DELETE ON TABLE
    $sqlInsert = "DELETE FROM annonces WHERE id=:idAnnonce ";
    $resultats = $connexion->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $resultats->bindValue(':idAnnonce', $idAnnonce, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultats->execute();

    // Now, i would like to delete image with name = $imageAnnonce in the folder /uploads
    // ... ??

    // How many row have been impacted ?
    echo $resultats->rowCount();

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
}



?>
```

Comment: [php delete file](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+delete+file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unlink` to delete a file:

```
unlink(pathtofile);
```

So in your case:

```
unlink ('uploads/'.$imageAnnonce);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `unlink()` function: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unlink.php.

For you, it will be:

```
unlink("uploads/$imageAnnonce");
```